# RxJava - Cache Observable Updates and Emit Largest Values

Tags: java, caching, java-8, stream, rx-java

I currently have an `Observable<ProductIDUpdate>` emitting an object that represents an update of a product ID. The update can either be the ID is an new `ADDITION` or has expired and requires `DELETION`.

```
public class ProductIDUpdate {

    enum UpdateType {
        ADDITION, DELETEION;
    }

    private int id;
    private UpdateType type;

    public ProductIDUpdate(int id) {
        this(id, UpdateType.ADDITION);
    }

    public ProductIDUpdate(int id, UpdateType type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I want to track the update with the largest ID value, hence I want to modify the stream so that the current highest ID is emitted. How would I cache the update items in the stream such that if the current highest ID is deleted, the next highest available ID is emitted?

Comment: Which stream, and which cache? These parts weren't clear enough to me.

Comment: There is no cache, the stream is the Observable of updates I am receiving. I am unsure how to process the data to just emit the values I require - I assumed a cache will be required for the expected behaviour.

Comment: And what do you call stream then? Is it literally a Java `Stream` or is it your observable object? Sorry still trying to get the problem.

Comment: Ok sorry, the stream is a RxJava Observable<ProductIDUpdate> stream - that is it emits ProductIdUpdate objects which I am receiving from a streaming source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Rx, but here's my understanding:

- you have a bunch of product ids. It's not clear to me whether you receive them over time as part of some messages being sent to your class or if you know all the ids from the beginning
- you want to create a stream on top of your source of product ids that emits the highest available id at any point in time

If my understanding is correct, how about using a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)? You cache ids in the queue with a reverse comparator (it keeps the smallest element at the top of the heap by default) and when you want to emit a new value you just pop the top value.

Answer (score 0):

Can something like that meet your requirements?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<ProductIDUpdate> products =
            Observable.just(new ProductIDUpdate(1, ADDITION),
                            new ProductIDUpdate(4, ADDITION),
                            new ProductIDUpdate(2, ADDITION),
                            new ProductIDUpdate(5, ADDITION),
                            new ProductIDUpdate(1, DELETION),
                            new ProductIDUpdate(5, DELETION),
                            new ProductIDUpdate(3, ADDITION),
                            new ProductIDUpdate(6, ADDITION));

    products.distinctUntilChanged((prev, current) -> prev.getId() > current.getId())
            .filter(p -> p.getType().equals(ADDITION))
            .subscribe(System.out::println,
                       Throwable::printStackTrace);

    Observable.timer(1, MINUTES) // just for blocking the main thread
              .toBlocking()
              .subscribe();
}
```

This prints:

```
ProductIDUpdate{id=1, type=ADDITION}
ProductIDUpdate{id=4, type=ADDITION}
ProductIDUpdate{id=5, type=ADDITION}
ProductIDUpdate{id=6, type=ADDITION}
```

If you remove the `filter()`, this prints:

```
ProductIDUpdate{id=1, type=ADDITION}
ProductIDUpdate{id=4, type=ADDITION}
ProductIDUpdate{id=5, type=ADDITION}
ProductIDUpdate{id=5, type=DELETION}
ProductIDUpdate{id=6, type=ADDITION}
```